Referring to another cell
I am writing a sheet to compare baseball teams and scores etc. Each team has its own sheet with a comparison to another ie
Arizona v Boston filename ariVbos.xlsx
Boston v Milwaukee f/name bosVmil.xlsx
On my input sheet I have :-
A1      B1      C1     D1     E1
team1   team2   away   home   total
                run    run    runs
                diff   diff

I need a way of looking at the cells in team1 and team2 and combing them to point to the run diffs and totals from the corresponding sheets.
IE
If A1 = bos and B1 = tex then excel would open the sheet c:/documents/baseball/A1B1.xlsx
and copy the values for away run difference, home run difference, and total runs into C1,D1,and E1
I have tried playing around with the INDIRECT function but am still getting #ref errors. Any ideas?

Can you share with us more about the code/formulae you are currently trying?

The setup described using different workbooks/worksheets to store data seems overly complicated or will make formula writing overly complicated. I suggest FIRST putting all your data in one table, then come back here if you still have questions about a formula you are trying to use.

Could you please show us the formula of INDIRECT function?
